# Influence compile order of form_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook

I've got multiple `form_alter`s in my D7 website. One contrib and one custom. I need the custom module to overwrite the contrib module. But for some reason, the custom module is committing second...
How can I change the processing order of the hook_alters in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pop into the `system` table in your database and change the `status` column for your module. If you want your hooks to run *before* another particular module's then change `status` to a smaller number than the other module's `status` in the table. If you want them to run after, change the `status` to a greater number.

You'll need to clear Drupal's cache once you've made the change in the table so it gets picked up.

See [How to update a module's weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238) for a fuller explanation.